# Javascript: A fast way to check if an element is in a two-dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a `nodes_object` array, which has the structure of the following kind:

```
  nodes_object = {
             1: {
                 source: '001',
                 name: 'A',
                 target: '004',
                 name: 'B'
                },
             2: {
                 source: '003',
                 name: 'C',
                 target: '001',
                 name: 'A'
                },
             }
```

Then I also have an array `sorted` which is structured in the following way:

```
     sorted = { 
             1: {
                val: '001',
                count: '100'
                },
             2: {
                val: '003',
                count: '80'
             }
```

I need to create a function, which would reiterate through the `nodes_object`, check if BOTH the `source` and the `target` are contained in one of the `sorted` `val` parameters, and if yes, proceed further.

So far I came up with the function below, which first reiterates through the `nodes_object`, then reiterates through the `sorted` to see if any of the elements is present within it, but I'm wondering  if there's a faster and a more efficient way to do that?

Thank you!

```
  for (var i = 0; i < nodes_object.length; i++) {

        var sourcein = null;
        var targetin = null;

        for (var j = 0; j < sorted.length; j++) {
            if (sorted[j].val == nodes_object[i][0]) {
                sourcein = 1;
            }
            if (sorted[j].val == nodes_object[i][2]) {
                targetin = 1;
            }
        }


        if ((sourcein) && (targetin)) {

                // Perform the function
        }
   }
```

Comment: Those are objects, not arrays.

Comment: @Barmar Not sure if they really are or whether it's just a weird notation used for the question.

Comment: Why are you using `null` and `1` rather than `false` and `true`?

Comment: @nnnnnn I later use those `sourcein` and `targetin` values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, to create arrays you use `[]`, not `{}`. So it should be:

```
nodes_object = [
    {
     source: '001',
     name: 'A',
     target: '004',
     name: 'B'
    },
    {
     source: '003',
     name: 'C',
     target: '001',
     name: 'A'
    },
];
```

and similarly for `sorted`.

Make an object whose keys are the `val` objects you want to test.

```
hash = {};
for (var k = 0; k < sorted.length; k++) {
    hash[sorted[k]] = true;
}
```

Then you can use `in hash` to test whether something is found in `sorted`:

```
var sourcein, targetin;
for (var i = 0; i < nodes_object.length; i++) {
    sourcein = nodes_object[i].source in hash;
    targetin = nodes_object[i].target in hash;
    if (sourcein && targetin) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: ...plus JavaScript technically does not have multi-dimensional arrays, but I know what the OP meant.

Comment: The OP wants to *check if BOTH the source and the target are contained in one of the sorted val parameters* (and this is how their sample code works. This leads to a different test: `if (nodes_object[i].source == nodes_object[i].target && nodes_object[i].source in hash) { ... }`

Comment: That's what I originally started writing. Then I noticed that his code checks the variables after the loop is done. Since he's just asking for a faster way to code it, I assumed the basic logic was correct, so I kept that.

Comment: So @Barmar do you think that solution above you proposed will be faster? Thank you so much for you help!